# How to add a sum of a column and all other rows of a table

Tags: sql

I have table as

```
 name  quentity
 pramo  1000
 ladkat 2000
```

And I want select output as total new row with sum

```
   name     quentity
   pramod   1000
   ladkat   2000
   total    3000
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use? What you are looking for is called `with Rollup`.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most databases support some version of `rollup` or `grouping sets`.  For instance:

```
select coalesce(name, 'Total') as name, sum(quantity) as quantity
from t
group by name with rollup;
```

or:

```
select coalesce(name, 'Total') as name, sum(quantity) as quantity
from t
group by grouping sets ((name), ()) ;
```

Note that these work with an aggregation query, so you need a `group by` clause.

Comment: @pamchya . . . Use the `GROUPING SETS` version.

Answer (score 1):

**SQL Server, You can try this:**

```
SELECT name,quentity
FROM [your-table]
UNION
SELECT 'Total',SUM(quentity)
FROM [your-table]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Union Operator, so would be something like this

```
select * from test.item
union
select "Total", sum(qty)  from test.item;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using UNION like:

```
(SELECT *
 FROM your_table)
    UNION 
(SELECT sum(quentity) as "total"
 FROM  your_table)
```

Comment: Single quotes are for string literals, use double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"total"`.